# my code is giving me a type error even though i have taken care of the type...please tell me where i have gone wrong

Tags: python-3.x, regex, for-loop, operating-system

i wrote the code attached below to convert files with dates of a particular format into another
i got this error
  File "E:\pranil\python\doing stuff with python\american dates to european.py", line 13, in 
    os.rename(filename, replacer)
TypeError: rename: src should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list

```
import os, random, re
os.chdir('.\\american date files')
for i in range(20):
    file = open(f'{random.randint(1, 12)}-{random.randint(1, 31)}-{random.randint(2000, 2099)}', 'w')
    file.close()
ame_dates = os.listdir()
ame_date = re.compile(r'(\d\d?)-(\d\d?)-(\d\d\d\d)')
euro_dates = [ame_date.sub(f'{ame_date.search(date).group(2)}-{ame_date.search(date).group(1)}-{ame_date.search(date).group(3)}', date) for date in ame_dates]
count = 0
for dirname, foldername, filename in os.walk(r'E:\pranil\python\doing stuff with python\american date files'):
    replacer = euro_dates[count]
    os.rename(filename, replacer)
    count += 1
```

Comment: Hi there. It could be worth tidying up your question to omit inappropriate language in the code and the description. Try printing the contents of euro_dates[count] to see if it is a list. I suspect that it might be.

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk` returns a tuple of strings and arrays, so your `filename` object looks like this: ['filename']

Which means when you try to use it in `os.rename`, it doesn't have a string like it expects, but an array of string(s). `os.rename(filename[0], replacer)` or something similar should work for you.